# { useTranslation } from "react-i18next" library outputs error

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import "../i18n";
const Loader = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>loading...</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
export default props => {
  const { t } = useTranslation(); //the problem is in this line

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <h1>{t("testTitle")}</h1>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

But it doesn't work. Instead, a red screen shows up with the following text: *A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified. Add a  component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display*

At the beginning, I thought the problem came from `<Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>` line, but after a couple of tries, I've fond out that it's actually coming for the `useTranslation()` line.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found what's causing the problem: although the `useTranslation()` line is inside the default component, it's out of the `<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>` scope. So the solution is to NOT export that component. Instead, you have to assign it into a variable, and then create a new component which wraps it:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import "../i18n";
const Loader = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>loading...</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
const FirstComponent = props => { //You assign it into a varible instead of exporting directly

  const { t } = useTranslation(); 

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <h1>{t("testTitle")}</h1>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default props => { //This is the component that you have to export instead

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <FirstComponent/>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Comment: I believe invoking `useTranslation` (if suspense is enabled) is allowed only underneath `<Suspense>` component.